# Why does my while loop gets stuck sometimes,but sometimes not in my "secret santa" program?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

im trying to create basic secret santa function where u can pass list of names to it and it will automaticlly generate random possibilites but while loop sometimes gets stuck and that's the weird part i can not understand why.

```
def santa(listi):
    from random import shuffle,choice
    my_dict = {}
    shuffle(listi)
    while len(my_dict) != len(listi):
        person = choice(listi)
        person2= choice(listi)
        if person!= person2 and person2 not in my_dict.values() and person not in my_dict.keys():
            my_dict.update({person:person2})
        else:
            continue
    return my_dict
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I can render some advice; always use "while len(a) < len(b)". The "!=" you used carries the risk that the first term might skip a few. E.g., "len(a)" could be all even numbers, and "len(b)" is an odd number, meaning that the two will *always* be unequal, and the loop infinite. The "<" will work no matter what, even if the values skip over each other, so long as its value is not shrinking.

Comment: lol as soon as i posted this question i tried that but it didn't work! Thanks for the advice ill use it a lot

Comment: It may be possible you end up with a single person that is not a key or value in the dictionary. Ie. 3 people `a,b,c`. You assign `[a:b, b:a]`. Then it will loop forever because it can't find a match for `c`.

Comment: Also your `else: continue` serves no purpose, and should be removed.

Comment: Why not just `my_dict = dict(zip(listi, listi[1:] + [listi[0]]))` after the `shuffle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So whats happening is sometimes it ends up in the case where one person (for example below person "Y") is the receiver and giver of the gift:

```
<class 'list'>: ['X', 'W', 'Y', 'Z']
<class 'dict'>: {'X': 'W', 'Z': 'X', 'W': 'Z'}
```

I ran your code several times in the PyCharm debugger before I got to this case. Your while loop condition is:

```
while len(my_dict) != len(listi):
```

and as you can see this will never be the case as your code is now locked as the if condition `person != person2` will never be passed.

You should take a look at your if condition again and if you cant figure it out mention me in a comment and I'll help you out. A good idea would be to check what possible combinations are left and if only the condition above is met i.e Y is the receiver and giver, discard the list and keep going. This will guarantee you will always exit but is by no means optimal.